# how to make the text size of the x and y axis labels and the title on matplotlib and prettyplotlib graphs bigger

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, prettyplotlib

I set the figure size of a matplotlib or prettyplotlib graph to be large.
As an example lets say the size is 80 height by 80 width.

The text size for the plot title, x and y axis labels (i.e. point label 2014-12-03 and axis label [month of year] become very small to the point they are unreadable.

How do I increase the size of these text labels? Right now I have to zoom in with the web browser to see them.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `size` property:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel('my x label', size = 20)
plt.ylabel('my y label', size = 30)
plt.title('my title', size = 40)
plt.xticks(size = 50)
plt.yticks(size = 60)
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
plt.xlabel('Smarts', size = 20)
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title('Histogram of IQ', size = 50)
plt.text(60, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$', size = 30)
plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 0.03])
plt.xticks(size = 50)
plt.yticks(size = 50)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---------- EDIT --------------

using pretty plot

```
fig, ax = plt.plot()
fig.suptitle('fig title', size = 80)
ax.set_title('my title', size = 10)
ax.set_xlabel('my x label', size = 20)
ax.set_ylabel('my y label', size = 30)
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(40) 
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(50)
```

--------- LEGEND --------------

use the `prop` property

```
ppl.legend(prop={'size':20})
plt.legend(prop={'size':20})
```

same command..

---

example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from prettyplotlib import brewer2mpl
import numpy as np
import prettyplotlib as ppl
np.random.seed(12)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.suptitle('fig title', size = 80)
ax.set_title('axes title', size = 50)
for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(60)
ax.set_ylabel("test y", size = 35)
for i in range(8):
    y = np.random.normal(size=1000).cumsum()
    x = np.arange(1000)
    ppl.plot(ax, x, y, label=str(i), linewidth=0.75)
ppl.legend(prop={'size':30})
fig.savefig('plot_prettyplotlib_default.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works great, is it also possible to increase the size of the Legend, and does prettyplot lib have an alternative syntax for specifying the size of the title, xlabel, ylabel, and x and y ticks? when I change plt to .ppt (for prettyplot lib) it fails.

Comment: Check the answer edit. The legend is gonna work in the same way for both plt and ppl.

Comment: Thanks @Joao Paulo - Is there a way of specifying the size of the title when it is inside the df.plot(title=MyTitle). if I move the plt.title(MyTitle, size=20) outside of the PLOT brackets then in my for loop it creates a title above every subplot and I don't want that. I want a single title for a group of subplots - but I don't know how to apply the size property when it's in the brackets plot(title=MyTitle).

Comment: you can set the title of the figure, using the `fig` object:

Comment: `fig.suptitle('axes title', size = 80)`

Comment: Do you really need to cycle on tick labels? Isn't there a single command to say: set the font of the xtick labels to n?